# What's the proper way to create human readable output for sqlite blob entries?

Tags: sqlite

What's the proper way to create human readable output from sqlite blob entries?  Specifically, if we have a table

```
create table blobs (data blob);
```

and we want to display the data, is there a way to install a custom printer where we can just execute the query

```
select data from blobs;
```

and have something intelligible print?  Alternatively, do we just execute a select query like

```
select make_readable(data) from blobs;
```

where `make_readable` converts the blob into something like a string?

Comment: How should that work for encrypted data, or a random bitstream?

Comment: @CL. I'm not sure.  For my situation, I don't have either.